# Offspring Generation From More than Two than Two Chromosomes

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I am writing a GA in Python for camera placement optimization to get the highest possible coverage. The GA is working fine for two cameras. I am doing the following when I need to generate offspring/child -

```
# each chromosome has 6 genes, [camera name, x location, y location, z location, x angle, and y angle]
mom = "CamA_X1_Y1_Z1_xangle1_yangle1"
dad = "CamB_X2_Y2_Z2_xangle2_yangle2"

child_1 = "CamA_X1_Y2_Z1_xangle2_yangle1"  
child_2 = "CamB_X2_Y1_Z2_xangle1_yangle2"
```

I am taking one gene from one chromosome followed by another gene from the next chromosome. The process is reversed for the second child.

The issue is I am having more than two (3/4) chromosome (camera). In that case what should be the proper process of generating the child?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is related to multi-parent crossover.  There are many ways you can go about this, but here are two:

1. Randomly select the child's gene from the pool of parents (for 3 parents, there is a ⅓ chance the child will inherit each gene)
2. Generate every permutation and select the top *k* to move on

Randomly selecting will be the best for time and memory, while generating the permutations will likely yield better results.  It looks like there would be 125 (5^3) permutations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick two parents from a pool of n parents.  Presumably each parent has a score with which to compare success.  Pick 2 or 3 potential parents at random with the best scoring of the set going forward to be an actual parent.  Then repeat to select the second parent.

This is [Tournament selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_selection) with a probability of 1.0 for the best chromosome in the tournament.  High scoring chromosomes have a better chance of being a parent than low-scoring ones, though the low-scoring chromosomes have a non-zero chance of having offspring.